# For an ideal $a \subset A$, $\operatorname{depth}_a M \geq n$ iff $H^i_a(M) = 0$ for all $i < n$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

This is Hartshorne exercise III.3.4(b), from 'Algebraic Geometry'. We define $H^i_a(-) = R^i\Gamma_a(-)$ where $\Gamma_a(-)$ is the functor taking modules $M$ to their submodules of elements which are killed by $a^r$ for some power $r$. This is supposed to be done by induction, since (a) is the base case. As such, we assume "$\operatorname{depth}_a M \geq n$ iff $H^i_a(M) = 0$ for all $i < n$" is true for some $n$ and seek to prove the statement for $n + 1$.

The idea I've seen online is to fix some non-zero divisor $x_1 \in a$ and then use the exact sequence $$0 \to M \stackrel{x_1}\to M \to M/x_1M \to 0$$ to give rise to the long exact sequence of cohomology $$\cdots \to H^{i -1}_a(M/x_1M) \to H^i_a(M) \to H^i_a(M) \to \cdots$$

Now, suppose that $H^i_a(M) = 0$ for $i < n + 1$. Then, by the long exact sequence above, $H^{i}(M/x_1M) = 0$ for $i < n$ so $\operatorname{depth}_a(M/x_1M) \geq n$. It then follows that $\operatorname{depth}_a(M) \geq n + 1$. This establishes one direction.

Conversely, suppose $\operatorname{depth}_a(M) \geq n + 1$. Then, $\operatorname{depth}_a(M/x_1M) \geq n$ so the long exact sequence and the induction hypothesis gives $$0 = H^{n - 1}_a(M/x_1M) \to H^n_a(M) \to H^n_a(M)$$ so that the induced map $H^n_a(M) \to H^n_a(M)$ is injective.

Now, it is claimed in solutions online that this map is given by multiplication by $x_1$, which would then force $H^n_a(M)$ to be zero since $H^n_a(M) = \Gamma_a(H^n_a(M))$. I do not understand why this map would be multiplication by $x_1$. I tried going back and looking at the induced maps of injective resolutions but that does not really clarify.

Is this the right approach? If so, how does one show that this map of cohomology is given by $[m] \mapsto x_1[m]$?

Thank you!

Comment: Understanding this explicitly in terms of injective resolutions works just fine. The point is that, since we're working in a category of modules, scalar multiplication by an element of the base ring is automatically a chain endomorphism of any chain complex. Then, apply this to an injective resolution of $M$.

Comment: @Thorgott The trouble is that while $x_1$ is a non-zero-divisor in $M$, I don't yet see why it would be a non-zero-divisor in any of the injective objects in the resolution. Moreover, I don't see why the resulting injection $(I^\cdot) \to (I^\cdot)$ would complete into an exact sequence of complexes $(I^\cdot) \to (I^\cdot) \to (J^\cdot)$ where $J^\cdot$ is an injective resolution of $M/x_1M$. Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515750/when-is-a-quotient-of-an-injective-module-injective) resolves my second issue since you can take $J^\cdot$ to be the quotients.

Comment: I didn't say anything about injectivity or exact sequences, you don't need that. If $f\colon M\rightarrow N$ is a homomorphism and $M\rightarrow I^{\bullet}$ and $N\rightarrow J^{\bullet}$ are injective resolutions, there is a chain map $I^{\bullet}\rightarrow J^{\bullet}$ that induces $f$ on $H^0$ and which is unique up to chain homotopy. Applying the functor $F$ to these complexes and taking cohomology in degree $n$, you obtain the induced map $R^nF(M)\rightarrow R^nF(N)$, which is well-defined. This is just how the derived functors are actually made into functors.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Thank you very much @Thorgott. I suppose that the key here is that the map on cohomology is unique for the map $f: M \to N$. This is indeed why $RF$ is a functor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just fleshing out Thorgott's helpful comments into an answer.

Let $I^\bullet$ be an injective resolution of $M$. Then, multiplication by $x_1$ gives a morphism of resolutions $I^\bullet \to I^\bullet$ inducing maps on $H_a^i(M) \to H^i_a(M)$ given $[m] \mapsto x_1[m]$. This means that the functor $R^i\Gamma_a$ sends the morphism $M \stackrel{x_1}\to M$ to the morphism $H_a^i(M) \stackrel{x_1}\to H^i_a(M)$, so that this is the morphism fitting into the exact sequence in question.

This uniqueness is what makes $R^i\Gamma_a$ into a functor, and it follows from the fact that morphisms of injective resolutions lifting any given map are unique up to homotopy.